# How do I switch my boot partition to a system partition

Tags: windows, boot

I have installed Windows 10 on an SSD drive but for some reason the boot partition was on another drive and now when I try to remove that other drive from the computer as expected the system won't load.

I have tried making the partition active with DISKPART and after that I tried to repair the boot sector with Windows installation DVD but that didn't help (Windows said they could not repair the startup). Then I tried BCDBOOT to make the system partition bootable but that didn't seem to work either. I know I can always reinstall Windows and fix the problem but I'd rather try and keep existing partitioning and spare myself of a long and tedious job of reinstalling windows and forgetting to install something I should have.

What I did with BCDBOOT: I boot into command prompt from my windows DVD. The boot partition is labeled C: and the system partition is labeled D:. When I used bcdboot I used it like bcdboot d:\Windows /s c: and it did not report any errors but still when I remove the other disk computer refuses to boot.

Any help is welcome no matter how trivial it may sound. I am obviously missing something here.

Thanks,

Goran

Comment: (I assume you won't mind reinstalling if all softwares,apps and personal files are preserved): Boot into windows > remove all other drives(including the one on which your current boot partition is) after successful boot > mount the iso (same iso you used for installation) > run the setup > carefully select to keep all personal files and apps when asked > after installation finished I think everything will on that drive as you want ; let me know if it works will add as answer afterwards

Comment: Will suggest to add screenshot of disk utility showing current partition state

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What do you mean with "but still when I remove the other disk computer refuses to boot."
Do you receive any error message?

Check if a directory called "Windows" on the SSD.
Try to use bcdboot with the running windows not with a live cd.
You could try to make a windows backup, remove the hdd, recover the backup with a live cd to the ssd. But you should make an other backup of your most important data.

Comment: I either get the message that there is no boot disk or that the boot sector is corrupt or invalid and I have to repair it with Windows installation DVD, But when I try to repair it I get the message that it failed to repair the startup.

Comment: I used bcdboot with running windows, changed the active partition rebooted and it prompted me to repair the startup with the Windows install DVD which I tried and this time it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What type of drive is the boot partition on? This can make a difference.

Since it sounds like a new install, my advice would be to save hassles in the future:

1. Go into BIOS
   1B) Set boot order to D:/ (assumed disk drive) then C:/ (assumed desired SSD drive) then E:/ (assumed other drive)
2. Use Disktools to wipe (format) both drive and all active partitions (a screwed up system partition could have something to do with this)
3. Disengage the nonessential drive (E:/)
4. Reboot to your Windows disk and install completely on the SSD drive (c:/)
5. insure Windows is working properly...
6. reattach additional drive

Comment: Troubleshooting the details of the problem seem inconsequential at this stage. I've been a tech installer for years and have learned not to give myself headaches when taking on other people's.

Comment: If you really want to troubleshoot your current set up for who knows what reason, you need to list what dependency files it's attempting to pull from the other disk maybe by adding that drive to another computer but whatever you do make sure you don't boot from that drive. If you're crazy bored you could clone the disk partition from the additional drive into a new free sector of your SSD. You probably need a 3rd party partition tool like partition magic or something as i believe stock win (powershell, whatever) doesn't deal with deallocating space from a partition to reallocate it.

Comment: I know that one of my options is a clean install but as I said in the original post I would like to avoid it and it looks to me as there should be a solution for it. I have image of the partition done using Macrium Reflect and I tried even reinstalling Windows from scratch and then retrieving the system from the image (in vague hope against my better judgement that it might fix the problem which shows how really disparate I am) which of course didn't work so I was hoping for any kind of direction I might look at to do this WITHOUT reinstalling Windows.